# laravel form submission showing 419 page expired

Tags: laravel, form-submit

why i am getting 419 error on form submitting.I have tried to change environment and also enable the debug true.But still not getting error just getting 419 page expired.I know why i am getting this page due to missing crsf field. But i want to see the actual error other than page expired.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: i am using the latest version 5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't see an actual error is because Laravel handles `HttpException`s by checking if a file exists for a specific HTTP error code and rendering that rather than rendering the error with Whoops or Synfony.

Out-of-the-box, Laravel comes with error files for `401`, `403`, `404`, `419`, `429`, `500` and `503` error pages. These are located at:

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views
```

If you would like to disable this behaviour when debug is enabled and you're not in production then you can add the following method to your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` class:

```
protected function renderHttpException(HttpExceptionInterface $e)
{
    if (app()->environment() !== 'production' && config('app.debug')) {
        return $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    }

    return parent::renderHttpException($e);
}
```

The above will prevent Laravel from checking to see if there is a specific error file for the exception.

Answer (score 4):

add @csrf token on the form field.

```
<form action="" method="">
@csrf
.
.
</form>
```

Here is the logic:

`@csrf` or `{{csrf_field()}}`
create input with `csrf_token`. Laravel post request search `_token`. If it doesn't exist it looks `x-csrf-token`. 
In this file:
`laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken`

on `tokensMatch()`.

Then if token doesn't exist, it throws an exception. 
In here: `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions`

```
prepareException()
```

If You are Using Ajax Call just add before send Method

```
beforeSend: function(xhr, type) {
                    if (!type.crossDomain) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
                    }
                    },
```

And Don't Forget to add Meta tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then it abort 419. I mean there is no real error. It just abort error page.

Comment: i know why i am getting this error .Just i want to see the complete error .

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling my hair off as in my case it was happening just on a single POST url where I was trying to update article post to my backend.

Token was always there, no permission issues with session folder, no whitespaces, regenerating app key didn't help. I was running out of clue, especially when updating different article posts were working good.

In my case what helped was to purge Cloudflare cache for the entire app. (My Laravel app lives behind Cloudflare DNS). Once I purged cache I was able to submit the form in my dashboard.

Still I don't know what was the culprit, but because error 419 is now gone I'm posting this - maybe it will help and if your know the culprit, please post as a comment.